# Since when did Merlin have an owl?

Tags: history-of-literature, arthurian-legend

I was reading some ten-year-old comments on a [Q&A about owls in *Harry Potter*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9746/31394) and learned that some versions of the Arthurian legend have the wizard Merlin possessing an owl which is called Archimedes. One comment by user [PLL](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/475/pll) claims:

> Archimedes wasn’t a Disney creation — The Sword in the Stone was originally a novel by T. H. White (it’s great fun), and Archimedes certainly appears in that. As far as I know he’s original to that book though, not in any older Arthurian legends.

Is this true? **Where does the idea of Merlin having an owl originate from?** And where did the name Archimedes for said owl first appear? (It's a hard one to search for on the internet, because web searches for `Merlin owl` lead mostly to pages about the [merlin bird of prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_(bird)).)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in D.A. Hosek's answer, Malory’s *Le Morte d'Arthur* was the primary source for White. In the *Morte d'Arthur* there is no mention of Merlin having an owl, or indeed any pet/familiar at all. Even physical descriptions of the wizard are very brief. Instead the character of Merlin in the *Once and Future King*, was not based on Arthurian legend, but on another source - White himself. As White's biographer, [Sylvia Warner](https://archive.org/details/thwhitebiography00warn), noted, the character and eccentricities of Merlin are clear images of White. He had recently been a schoolteacher at Stowe school, and took the opportunity to make Merlin what he considered to be an ideal schoolteacher, operating in an ideal educational environment:

> he gave himself an ideal old age, free from care and the contradiction
> of circumstances, practising an enlightened system of education on a
> chosen pupil, embellished with an enchanter's hat, omniscient,
> unconstrainable and with a sink where the crockery washed itself up.
> As Merlyn, White had the time of his life: the brief dazzle of being
> head of the English Department at Stowe was a farthing candle to it.

Apart from furnishing Merlin with many of his most prized possessions - his beard, his knitting, his opinions - he also gave him possession of his pet owl. White kept quite a menagerie of animals, and at the time it consisted of his beloved red setter and some birds:

> He went on keeping Cully [a goshawk] and two sparrowhawks and presently added an
> owl, whom he called Archimedes

[A hawk called Cully is also familiar to readers of *The Sword in the Stone*.]

As to why he chose the name Archimedes, Warner does not give any mention, nor is it mentioned in any of White's published letters (*The White - Garnett Letters*, and *Letters to a friend : the correspondence between T. H. White and L. J. Potts*). But I think the association of owls with wisdom and Athena, and thence to Greek culture, makes the choice of the name of a Greek philosopher fairly natural.

Comment: Ah, I would have called Archimedes (the man, not the owl) a mathematician or even a physicist rather than a philosopher, but you are using the word appropriately in its older sense.

Comment: Though since Merlyn lived backwards, maybe it would make more sense to have named Merlyn's owl after a future (from our point of view) scholar?  (Not that Merlyn wouldn't have heard of Archimedes)

Answer (score 12):

White’s primary source for the characters and plot in *The Once and Future King* (of which *The Sword in the Stone* is a part) is Malory’s *Le Morte d'Arthur* which in turn derives from the earlier prose *Merlin*.

As far as I recall, there was no owl in those books. Furthermore, T.H. White was an amateur falconer (an interest displayed in many ways throughout *The Sword in the Stone*) so it would seem that the owl would be original to White.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that as well as well caring for hawks, THW nursed an injured owl back to health. Don't know if he named it though  ;)

Comment: This answer is quite likely correct, but there's a bit too much supposition and guesswork for me to accept it. If you can find a quote from White where he *said* that he created the owl, that would do it. If you did a more exhaustive search of pre-White Arthurian literature to see if there was an earlier mention of Merlin having an owl, that would also be great.

Comment: It seems he kept (at least) three owls, one of which *was* called Archimedes (and one of the others was called "Silvia Daisy Pouncer".)

Comment: It's quite a big leap from Malory in the 15th century to White in the 1930s, and [a lot of retellings of Arthurian myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Arthur#Decline,_revival,_and_the_modern_legend) appeared in the interim, especially in the 19th century. So saying "it wasn't in Malory" can hardly be considered proof it was original to White.